# ExpressJS router middleware cannot render views

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to set up routes using Express Router middleware. Except for **index.jade** ( which is at path **http:localhost:3000/** ), any other template under the **views** directory are not being rendered and the router fails to send any response set in the module. Below is a snippet of my code:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
};

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (!err) {
    return next();
  }

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });

  console.error(err.stack);
});

module.exports = app;
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'ReQuest' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside **routes/users.js** you use `router.get('/users'`. I believe that should be `router.get('/'`. The way you have it set up would only handle requests to http://localhost:3000/users/users.

Comment: If I wanted to use `router.get('/users')`, what needs to happen in **app.js**?

Comment: The call to `app.use('/users', users)` inside **app.js** mounts the router to the /users endpoint. Inside **users.js**, the root of that mount point is represented as /, and routes are considered relative from there. For example, you'd handle requests made to http://localhost:3000/users with `router.get('/'`, and requests made to http://localhost:3000/users/prefs with `router.get('/prefs'`. It was designed this way so routes could easily be mounted to any endpoint without you having to alter any code inside the route itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to render another view in index.js i.e.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('otherview', { title: 'ReQuest' });
});
```

If that's the case, then I'd make sure they are named `otherview.jade`

Otherwise, if you are trying to get your users route to render a view then you just need to include `res.render('users');` and create an appropriate users.jade file in your views directory.